# Date Range Not Updating In Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a SQL query that is pulling in the last 90 days worth of data. I then have a pivot table where I have the dates grouped by 30 days and put into columns. This way I get a 30, 60, 90 day column totals for the data coming in. The issue is the dates aren't automatically updating in the ranges. So day 91 is still showing up but its not in the data set anymore. I left the automatic data group unchecked because I don't want it to have a beginning or end but to just roll. Is that possible?

The only other thought I have is to do a conditional field in the power query looking at the date ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! You need to create two columns in your power query.
The first is just a how many days from today.

```
Duration.Days (DateTime.Date(DateTime.LocalNow()) - [LedgerDate])
```

Then a column to group them together.

```
if [DaysFromToday] >= 61
then "90"
else if [DaysFromToday] <=60 and [DaysFromToday] >=31 then "60"
else "30"
```